# Scrapy spider does not store state (persistent state)

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi have a basic spider that runs to fetch all links on a given domain. I want to make sure it persists its state so that it can resume from where it left. I have followed the given url http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html .But when i try it the first time it runs fine and i end it with Ctrl+C and when I try to resume it the crawl stops on the first url itself.

Below is the log when it ends:

```
2016-08-29 16:51:08 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 896,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 35320,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 149,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 29, 16, 51, 8, 837853),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 28,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'offsite/domains': 22,
 'offsite/filtered': 23,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 29, 16, 51, 7, 821974)}
2016-08-29 16:51:08 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Something.items import SomethingItem

class maxSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'something'
  allowed_domains = ['thecheckeredflag.com', 'inautonews.com']
  start_urls = ['http://www.thecheckeredflag.com/', 'http://www.inautonews.com/']

  rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)


  def parse_obj(self,response):

    for link in LinkExtractor(allow=self.allowed_domains,deny =() ).extract_links(response):
        item = SomethingItem()
        item['url'] = link.url
        yield item
        #print item
```

Scrapy version: Scrapy 1.1.2

Python version: 2.7

I am new to scrapy, if i need to post any more info please let me know.

Comment: What does your Terminal/CMD call look like?  Is it using syntax like they suggest:  `scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1`?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. it also runs the first time properly but when i resume the above are the stats for the resume

Comment: Can you paste the log for when your scraper starts to run? Where the configuration happens.

Comment: @kiran.koduru, i figured out what was going on, I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this was happening was due to the spider process being killed abruptly.

The spider was not shutting down properly when I hit the Ctrl+C. Now, when the crawler shuts down properly the first time, it resumes properly too.

So basically, make sure that you see the crawler ends/shuts down properly for it to resume.