# How to persist state when the crawler dies abruptly?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

this quetion is in reference to [Scrapy spider does not store state (persistent state)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211490/scrapy-spider-does-not-store-state-persistent-state)

I have followed the following link to persist state of the crawler http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html

Now this works perfectly fine when the crawler ends properly, with a interrupt or a Ctrl+C.

I have noticed that the spider does not shut down properly when

1. You hit Ctrl +C multiple times.
2. The server capacity is hit.
3. Any other reason due to which it ends abruptly

The spider when runs again , shuts itself down on the first url crawled.

How to achieve a persistent state of the crawler when something like above happens?
Cause or else it ends up crawling the whole bunch of urls again.

Logs when the spider runs again:

```
2016-08-30 08:14:11 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.2 started (bot: maxverstappen)
2016-08-30 08:14:11 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'maxverstappen.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['maxverstappen.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'maxverstappen'}
2016-08-30 08:14:11 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.spiderstate.SpiderState']
2016-08-30 08:14:11 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-08-30 08:14:11 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['maxverstappen.pipelines.MaxverstappenPipeline']
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.inautonews.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.thecheckeredflag.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.inautonews.com/> (referer: None)
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.thecheckeredflag.com/> (referer: None)
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.inautonews.com/> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.newsnow.co.uk': <GET http://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Life+&+Style/Motoring>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.americanmuscle.com': <GET http://www.americanmuscle.com/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.extremeterrain.com': <GET http://www.extremeterrain.com/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.autoanything.com': <GET http://www.autoanything.com/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.bmwcoop.com': <GET http://www.bmwcoop.com/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.automotorblog.com': <GET http://www.automotorblog.com/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'twitter.com': <GET https://twitter.com/inautonews>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.facebook.com': <GET https://www.facebook.com/inautonews>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'plus.google.com': <GET https://plus.google.com/+Inautonewsplus>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.histats.com': <GET http://www.histats.com/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.hamiltonf1site.com': <GET http://www.hamiltonf1site.com/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.joshwellsracing.com': <GET http://www.joshwellsracing.com/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.jensonbuttonfan.net': <GET http://www.jensonbuttonfan.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.fernandoalonsofan.net': <GET http://www.fernandoalonsofan.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.markwebberfan.net': <GET http://www.markwebberfan.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.felipemassafan.net': <GET http://www.felipemassafan.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.nicorosbergfan.net': <GET http://www.nicorosbergfan.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.nickheidfeldfan.net': <GET http://www.nickheidfeldfan.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.lewishamiltonblog.net': <GET http://www.lewishamiltonblog.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.timoglockfan.net': <GET http://www.timoglockfan.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.jarnotrullifan.net': <GET http://www.jarnotrullifan.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.brunosennafan.net': <GET http://www.brunosennafan.net/>
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 896,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 35353,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 149,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 30, 8, 14, 12, 724932),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 28,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'offsite/domains': 22,
 'offsite/filtered': 23,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 30, 8, 14, 12, 13456)}
2016-08-30 08:14:12 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Do you have logs for _when the spider when runs again , shuts itself down on the first url crawled_?

Comment: From a first look at the logs, I don't see that the spider shuts itself down: it stops because no new URL is being requested. What do you have in your `start_urls`? You seem to be crawling a lot of domains but the default OffsiteMiddleware filters them out. `http://www.inautonews.com` was apparently already fetched in the previous run. Is it expected to have all those domains filtered?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is seperating discovery and consumer logic by having two spiders. One to discovery product urls another to consume those urls and return results for every one of them. If for some reason the consumer dies mid run it can easily resume the crawl because discovery queue was not affected by this crash.

There's already a great tool for scrapy by the scrapy guys which does exactly that. It's called [Frontera](https://github.com/scrapinghub/frontera)

> Frontera is a web crawling framework consisting of crawl frontier, and
>   distribution/scaling primitives, allowing to build a large scale
>   online web crawler.
>
> Frontera takes care of the logic and policies to follow during the
>   crawl. It stores and prioritises links extracted by the crawler to
>   decide which pages to visit next, and capable of doing it in
>   distributed manner.

It sounds complicated but it's pretty straigh-forward. However if you run something small scale and one off you might just want to approach this manually. You can run discovery spider and output results in json then parse that json in a persistant manner(i.e. popping values out of it) in your consumer spider.

Comment: I tried using Frontera but was not able to get that working. i will try it out again. The way I am doing it is as you mentioned. 1 spider to get list of urls and the other to parse them, but when the first one dies, i don't want it to start all over again.

Comment: @RiteshKsheersagar Maybe have it crawl in batches. You can most likely set up a batch system using categories of products or something along those lines. setup category order and resume from specific category if crash occurs during the crawl of it, so in this case at worst you'd have to recrawl only one category as opposed to the whole page.